# Running Paho javascript example crashes network connection because of connect loop

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm trying to connect to a local mosquitto mqqt broker via websockets and the paho javascript client. However, using the example shown at https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/ crashes my network connection. In the chrome or ie console I found the problem: The connection is made over and over again (function onConnect is called multiple times per second).

```
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});  
// called when the client connects
function onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("Connection was successful");
  client.subscribe("World");
  message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
  message.destinationName = "World";
  client.send(message);
}
```

On the broker I can see the client connecting:

```
New client connected from 192.168.1.3 as web_78 (c1, k60, u'user123').
```

But the message does not get broadcasted by the client. When I terminate the browser, I see on the client:

```
Socket error on client web_78, disconnecting.
```

The same thing happens, when I try different Codeexample like this one: https://jpmens.net/2014/07/03/the-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-gets-websockets-support/

I'm using mosquitto version 1.5 on my Raspberry Pi and have really no Idea, how I can get this running. Maybe the problem is the mosquitto server and not the client?

This is the part of my mosquitto.conf where I define the ports

```
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

Other clients can connect (e.g via paho python) and mqtt (without websockets).

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
1530009485: mosquitto version 1.5 starting
1530009485: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1530009485: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1530009485: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1530009485: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1530009485: New connection from 192.168.1.51 on port 1883.
1530009485: New client connected from 192.168.1.51 as DVES_9CE05F (c1, k15, u'johann').
```

Any help would be highly appreaciated!

EDIT Update:

The problem must be within my server, as I can access public broker like HiveMQ.

Comment: Are you using the paho example unchanged (apart from the address of the broker)?

Comment: yes, just changed the ip address and the port.

Comment: I've just built the v1.5 source on x86_64 Ubuntu and it's behaving properly. Where did you get your raspberry pi build?

Comment: Also it looks like you edited the example to change the client id and set a username and password, please update the question with that code change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There is a problem related to libwebsockets in Mosquitto 1.5.x, at least in the version that are installed on Raspberry Pi with Raspbian jessie. When I downgraded Mosquitto to 1.4.15 this problem was solved for me.

Read about it in, https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1050